# Is there a way to move seekbar as song is playing in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am trying to get the seekbar to move as the song is playing. I have the following in my code which displays the seekbar.

```
<div class="playbackBar">
                            
        <span class="progressTime current">0.00</span>

        <div class="progressBar">
            <div class="progressBarBg">
                <div :style="'width:'+progress+'%'" class="progress"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <span class="progressTime remaining">0.00</span>

    </div>
```

The following code plays and pause the song among other things.

```
<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return{
            current: {},
            index: 0,
            isPlaying: false,
            progress: 0,
            songs: [
                {
                    title: 'Sample',
                    artist: 'Sample Artist',
                    src: '/storage/audio/sample.mp3'
                }
            ],
            player: new Audio()
        }
    },
    methods: {
        seekBar(mouse, progressBar){
            var percentage = mouse.offsetX / $(progressBar).width() * 100;
            var seconds = player.audio.duration * (percentage / 100);
            player.setTime(seconds);
        },
        play(song){
            if(typeof song.src != "undefined"){
                this.current = song

                this.player.src = this.current.src
            }
           
            this.player.play()
            this.player.addEventListener('ended', function () {
                this.index++;
                if (this.index > this.songs.length - 1) {
                    this.index = 0;
                }

                this.current = this.songs[this.index];
                this.play(this.current);
            }.bind(this));
            this.isPlaying = true;
        },
        pause(){
            this.player.pause();
            this.isPlaying = false;
        }
    },
    created(){
        this.current = this.songs[this.index];
        this.player.src = this.current.src;
    }
}
</script>
```

But the problem is getting the seekbar to move when playing the song, is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Could you please make a live example on https://stackblitz.com/ to reproduce your problem?

Comment: @Duannx here is the live example https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-hwdvrl?file=src/App.vue. Another question is that after a song plays it doesn't go to the next one. Any solution for that too??